# My webpage has infinite scrolling, how should I test it?

Tags: testing, selenium, infinite-scroll

I am testing infinite scroll feature of my web application on a variety of pages. What aspects should I keep in mind? 
What should be automated, using WebDriver for example. 
The website is primarily targeting iOS/Android devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend NOT automating any UI feature, at least the visual part.  I have found that testing functionality is fantastic with WebDriver, but that UI is harder, and generally not useful with automation.

For example, you could write a test that scrolls the page down, and verifies that new content is loaded.  However, you would have no idea whether or not the layout of the content is any good, or even if its on the part of the page you are looking at, *unless* you thought of each possible scenario where the UI could be wrong, and you tested for each.

That being said, I would still use the UI to make sure it functions.  I would scroll down the page, and click on a link to make sure that that link works.  Rather than going to a URL, I would use the menu at the top.

In summation, *I would test that the features function properly, but not test that the look good*.  That should be done in manual testing.

Comment: How is so-called-infinite scrolling not "functionality"?  Lots of folks test the paging functions of their websites using automation, and it makes just as much sense to test that scrolling off the bottom of the page loads additional content.

Comment: Look at my last two paragraphs.  I would test that it actually loads new content, but not that it looks good.

Comment: "_I would recommend NOT automating any UI feature._" is a pretty strong statement, even if you undercut it later on.

Answer (score 1):

1. For UI testing (design) you can try [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/)
2. Here is [Sikuli Api](https://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/) you can integrate with WebDriver

Only issue is that Sikuli is not testing picture pixel by pixel... try it and you'll see PROS and CONS